# DB2 - The data type of the source value is not compatible with the data type of the target column, variable,

Tags: stored-procedures, types, db2, return

I have the following stored procedure created in db2. However it gives an error stating that `"[SQL0408] Value for column, variable, or parameter NUMERIC1 not compatible. Cause . . . . . :   The data type of the source value is not compatible with the data type of the target column, variable, or parameter NUMERIC1"` in the return statement.

```
 CREATE or replace PROCEDURE mbs.mbstest2912()
        
          LANGUAGE SQL
          BEGIN atomic
       
       DECLARE numeric1  numeric(3,2);  
       
        set numeric1 =1.22;
        return numeric1 ;
        end
```

I dont see any root cause for this.How is it possible to rectify this error?

Comment: Always specify your Db2-SERVER platform (Z/os, i-series,  linux/unix/windows/cloud) and VERSION when asking for help. The answer can differ per platform and version.  Look up the error code in your Db2-server documentation to get information about the meaning of the mesage and how to resolve it.  The `RETURN` statement can only return an integer value.

Comment: Hi thanks. Anyway when I tried integer it works. But I need to return values for decimals/numeric

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the [RETURN](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=pl-return-statement) statement documentation link.

> **expression**
> Specifies a value that is returned from the routine:
>
> If the routine is a scalar function, ...
> If the routine is a table function, ..
> **If the routine is a procedure, the data type of expression must be INTEGER**. If the expression evaluates to the null value, a
> value of zero is returned.

Use output parameter if you want to return result of some custom data type.